# JQuery - Replace table text value with FontAwesome image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to replace html table data values with FontAwesomeFonts using Javascript \ JQuery.

I have two funcitons that replace the cell value based on the content of the cell, however there are some cells that may be empty so I want to search for the cells by Id instead.

Can someone please help me by telling \ showing me where in my code how I would search for these values by Id then I can do this across each cell in my table.

```
<table class="table">
  <th>
    Result
  <th/>
  <td id="Result">
    Success
  <td/>
 <table/>
```

Then in my js file i have this which works, but I want to know how to change the value by Id rather than by the contents

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("td:contains('Success')").html('<img src="../Static/Images/GreenTick.png" alt="Success" height="40px" width="50px"/>');
});

$(document).ready(function () {
$("td:contains('Fail')").html('<img src="../Static/Images/red-cross-md.png" alt="Success" height="40px" width="50px"/>');
});
```

Thanks

Simon

Comment: `$("#Result").html("your html here")`

Comment: I would do a search by class instead - ids are meant to be unique so you would have to use an attribute selector (which is less performant than a class selector).  Also your table doesn't have a `tr` and your closing slashes are on the wrong side of the tag

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: FIY: that's not how to use FontAwesome, btw. The point of FontAwesome is that you don't have to use images but characters of the font instead.

Comment: @low_rents the other cells are using the font awesome, and what I ma trying to do is find the cells so i can change the text for the font awesome icons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('.table td').each(function (){
        if($.trim($(this).text()) == 'Success'){
            //this will replace success text with success image
            $(this).text('<img src="your-success-image-path">');
        }else if($.trim($(this).text()) == 'fail'){
            //this will replace fail text with fail image
            $(this).text('<img src="your-fail-image-path">');
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <table class="table">
  <th>
    Result
  <th/>
  <td id="Result">
    Success
  <td/>
  <td id="Result">
    fail
  <td/>
 <table/>
</table>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('.table td').each(function (){
        if($.trim($(this).text()) == 'Success'){
            //this will replace success text with success image
            $(this).text('<img src="your-success-image-path">');
        }else if($.trim($(this).text()) == 'fail'){
            //this will replace fail text with fail image
            $(this).text('<img src="your-fail-image-path">');
        }
      });
    });

});
```

Comment: I am running jquery-1.11.3 will your 2.1.1 affect what I am trying to run?

Comment: no that will work fine, you do not need to include jquery again, your 1.11.3 will work fine

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly now must have been suffering from fat fingers!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Jquery Id selector as follows to change the html of element if it contains the desired text (in this case "Success"):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("#Result:contains('Success')").html('<img src="../Static/Images/GreenTick.png" alt="Success" height="40px" width="50px"/>');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use in contains(Success) not contains('Success')

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("td:contains(Success)").html('<img src="../Static/Images/GreenTick.png" alt="Success" height="40px" width="50px"/>');
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("td:contains(Fail)").html('<img src="../Static/Images/red-cross-md.png" alt="Success" height="40px" width="50px"/>');
});
```

Comment: my code for that bit works but will take that on board thank you

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are quite new to jQuery since you don't know basic selectors. `$("#id-name")` selects a DOM id, `$(".class-name")` selects a DOM class.

```
$("#Result").html('<img src="../Static/Images/GreenTick.png" alt="Success" height="40px" width="50px"/>');
```

Comment: I am extremely new... two days in...  what I am looking for is as per the solution from Anshul, if the table cell value is this then this, or if its that then do this instead.

Comment: @SimonPrice ok, well - in your question you wanted to select by id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ID Selector of JQuery which is $("#id")

So here it is;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Result").html('<img src="../Static/Images/GreenTick.png"     alt="Success" height="40px" width="50px"/>');
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Result").html('<img src="../Static/Images/red-cross-md.png"     alt="Success" height="40px" width="50px"/>');
});
```